# Connection error between local machine and AWS EC2 instance through python code

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sockets, amazon-ec2, time

When I run the following code, I get an error saying :

**TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond**

```
# server3.py on EC2 instance
import socket
from threading import Thread
from SocketServer import ThreadingMixIn

# TCP_IP = socket.gethostbyaddr("your-ec2-public_ip")[0]
TCP_IP = socket.gethostbyaddr("3.129.88.101")[0]
TCP_PORT = 60001
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

print 'TCP_IP=',TCP_IP
print 'TCP_PORT=',TCP_PORT

class ClientThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self,ip,port,sock):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.sock = sock
        print " New thread started for "+ip+":"+str(port)

    def run(self):
        filename='mytext.txt'
        f = open(filename,'rb')
        while True:
            l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
            while (l):
                self.sock.send(l)
                #print('Sent ',repr(l))
                l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
            if not l:
                f.close()
                self.sock.close()
                break

tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
tcpsock.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
threads = []

while True:
    tcpsock.listen(5)
    print "Waiting for incoming connections..."
    (conn, (ip,port)) = tcpsock.accept()
    print 'Got connection from ', (ip,port)
    newthread = ClientThread(ip,port,conn)
    newthread.start()
    threads.append(newthread)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

```
# client3.py on local machine
#!/usr/bin/env python

#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import time

#TCP_IP = 'ip-ec2-instance'
TCP_IP = '3.129.88.101'
TCP_PORT = 60001

BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

clock_start = time.perf_counter()
time_start = time.time()

with open('received_file', 'wb') as f:
    print 'file opened'
    while True:
        #print('receiving data...')
        data = s.recv(1024)
        #print('data=%s', (data))
        if not data:
            f.close()
            print 'file close()'
            break
        # write data to a file
        f.write(data)

print('Successfully get the file')
s.close()
print('connection closed')

clock_end = time.clock()
time_end = time.time()

duration_clock = clock_end - clock_start
print 'clock:  start = ',clock_start, ' end = ',clock_end
print 'clock:  duration_clock = ', duration_clock

duration_time = time_end - time_start
print 'time:  start = ',time_start, ' end = ',time_end
print 'time:  duration_time = ', duration_time
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong and it would be helpful if someone could help.

Comment: you need to adjust the network rules on the ec2 instance (in the aws console... under networking I think)

Comment: Check your program, subnet, security group and NACL: 1. Did your program work correctly in EC2 instance?  2. Is subnet public or private. If it's private, did you have NAT instance or NAT Gateway. 3. Did you allow Inbound your local IP and port 60001. 4. Did NACL restrict port and IP?

Comment: @luanvu Thanks for your help! I missed out on the third step and once I fixed that it worked